# Finding hilbert space basis

Tags: hilbert-spaces, vectors, quantum-mechanics

I already have two vectors expressed in basis $\{|u_1 \rangle, |u_2\rangle, |u_3\rangle\}$:

$$|\phi_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(|u_1\rangle + i |u_2\rangle - |u_3\rangle) $$

$$|\phi_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u_1\rangle - i |u_2\rangle) $$

and I have to find a third one to form an orthonormal basis. How do I do that ?

I tried using the relations :

$$\langle\phi_1\mid\phi_3\rangle = 0$$

$$\langle\phi_2\mid\phi_3\rangle= 0$$

$$\langle\phi_3\mid\phi_3\rangle = 1$$

Which leads to :

$$x_3 = 2x_1$$

$$x_2 = ix_1$$

$$x_1^{*}x_1 + x_2^{*}x_2 + x_3^{*}x_3 = 1$$

where $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are the components of the third vector.
But I can't seem to go further than that...

Comment: Tip: Use "rangle" $\rangle $ and "langle" $\langle $ instead of $>$ and $<$.

Comment: Hint: By taking the "outer product" of $\sqrt {3}\phi_1$ and $\sqrt{2}\phi_2$ we obtain the vector $(-i,-1,-2i)$ which obeys all but the third relation.

Comment: Note that the method you've proposed will produce an *orthonormal* basis, whereas in the question you didn't specify that requirement. However, the work you've done will give you an answer. In the last three equations for $x_1, x_2, x_3$ that you wrote, you can substitute the 1st and 2nd equations into the 3rd into order to solve for $x_1$ (not a unique solution), from which you can obtain $x_2, x_3$.

Comment: I'm not sure of what a "outer product" is. Isn't that a cross product ? So by taking $\phi_1 \times \phi_2$  I get a third vector $N_3\phi_3$ orthogonal to the other two. And if I normalize it to 1, I get $N_3 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$, correct ?

Comment: I changed {$|u_1 \rangle, |u_2\rangle, |u_3\rangle$} to $\{|u_1 \rangle, |u_2\rangle, |u_3\rangle\}$, with the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ inside rather than outside of MathJax.  That is standard and proper usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user1234161 Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remember that $\{|u_1\rangle, |u_2\rangle, |u_3\rangle\} \not\subseteq \operatorname{span}(|\phi_1\rangle, |\phi_2\rangle)$ -- in fact the span might not include any of them.  So just start checking whether each of your basis vectors is in the span and stop when you find one that isn't.

Clearly [$|u_1\rangle \not\in \operatorname{span}(|\phi_1\rangle, |\phi_2\rangle)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+%7B%7B1%2Ci%2C-1%7D%2C%7B1%2C-i%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D).  So, because this Hilbert space is $3$-dimensional, $\{|u_1\rangle, |\phi_1\rangle, |\phi_2\rangle\}$ is a basis for the space.

Note that this is not an *orthonormal* basis.  But you can easily make it into one via the Gram-Schmidt process.